# (NUXT) How to add component in sweet alert 2

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, sweetalert2

I tried to add a component in swal by the following method.

```
this.$swal({ html: '<Card :assignment="{}"></Card>' })
```

But it ends up giving me this error,

```
error: The "Card" component has been registered but not used  vue/no-unused-components
```

Any leads will be appreciated

Answer (score -1):

The error you're receiving is just a linting error being thrown.  It's being thrown because the linter expects you to use the `Card` component inside the  tags.

Try the following:

```
// inside your Vue component

components: { 
// eslint-disable-next-line vue/no-unused-components
  Card 
}
```